# Can the D4 or D100 give me Godhead?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I'm trying to complete my collection through D100 spam. I've gotten to Womb II, however, and my build seems to have stopped changing. I did unlock a few other items this way (such as The Body), but Godhead remains uncollected.

Can the D4 or D100 give me Godhead?

Comment: Good to know that you can get "The Lost" items in that way.

Comment: @pinckerman only after you unlock them the hard way (you must collect every item at least once to get Platinum God's)

Comment: Ok, this seems reasonable.

Comment: @badp actually you don't need to unlock them to be able to get them with the D4 or the D100. You'd still need the unlock to get them through normal means and to get Real Platinum God anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've gotten to Womb II, however, and my build seems to have stopped changing.

That means you've depleted the item room pool, and now you're perpetually getting Breakfasts. I'm gonna guess your red heart containers were maxed out too, right?

> Can the D4 or D100 give me Godhead?

The D4 and the D100 can only reroll your items into items from the item room pool. Since Godhead is an Angel Room-only item, you will never reroll into it.

Also, I want to clear up a misconception: You CAN get items that you haven't unlocked yet through D4/D100 rerolling. For example, you can get the Mind, the Soul, and the Body with the D4 without ever having unlocked the Lost.

EDIT: I'm getting conflicting information about the D4 (and therefore the D100 as well); the [official wiki](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/D4) states that it can only reroll into item room items, while the [BoI Cheat Sheet](http://platinumgod.co.uk/) says it will reroll each item into another item from the same pool. I personally don't recall getting angel room items with the D100, but I'll double-check with Reddit to be sure.

Comment: Do the D4 and D100 still use only the item room pool when used in an angel room? "Normally" there's one pool per room, not one per item.

Comment: Not only was it maxed out, but it seemed that I was getting the items I  was having multiple times. My final set of items happened to have Number One and my range decreased with every D100 reroll.