# Can the D4 put items back into the pool?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I was doing a BASEMENT run and I got the D6, D20, and D4. Before breakfast, I used the D4 a few times and after a few more rolls (D6+D20 rolls), I got breakfast. I went to the next level and to my surprise, there were still items that weren't breakfast. I even picked up the small rock, which I distinctly remember picking up earlier in the run. Could the small rock have been put back into the item pool by the D4?

Comment: [Apparently the D4 (and the D100) will (try and) only replace items with other items in the same item pool](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/203128/23), and [the small rock is found in no pool whatsoever](http://platinumgod.co.uk/rebirth).

Answer (score 2):

[Apparently the D4 (and the D100) will (try and) only replace items with other items in the same item pool](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/203128/23), and [the small rock is found in no pool whatsoever](http://platinumgod.co.uk/rebirth):

[image]

Hence, you can never get this item by D4 (or D100) rerolling.